# Proving contour integral vanishes along an arc

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I was evaluating the following integral by means of contour integral

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(a \theta)\cos^b(\theta)\,d \theta=\frac{\pi}{2^{b+1}(b+1)} \,\frac{1}{\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{a+b+2}{2},\frac{b-a+2}{2} \right)}
\end{aligned}
$$

For $a,b \in \operatorname{C}$, $\operatorname{Re}(a)>\operatorname{Re}(b)$, and $\operatorname{R}(b)>-1$.To this end I chose the following integrand

$$F(z)=z^{a-b-1}(1+z^2)^b=z^{a-b-1}(z+i)^b(z-i)^b$$

Which cleary for non integrers $a$ and $b$ has three branch points.

We want to compute the following integral along the  contour $C_r$ below, where the dotted lines indicate the branch cuts. Since inside this contour the integrand has no singularities, by Cauchy´s teorem, the integral equals zero. Hence:

$$\oint_{C_r}  z^{a-b-1}(1+z^2)^b \,dz=0$$

[image]

My question is regarding the integrals along the semicircles  $A_1$,$A_2$ and $A_3$ that should vanish in the limit that $r$ goes to zero. I want to show that in fact those integrals vanish.

I will show the method I used for the contour $A_2$, the others should follow the same lines. I would like to know if this method is correct:

Choosing $z=re^{i \theta}$ the integral over $A_2$ becomes

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{A_2}&=\int_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2}  \left(re^{i \theta} \right)^{a-b-1}\left(1+r^2e^{2i \theta} \right)^b ire^{i \theta}\,d \theta\\
&=-i r^{a-b}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{i \theta(a-b)}e^{b \ln\left(1+r^2e^{2i \theta} \right)}\,d \theta\\
&=-i r^{a-b}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{i \theta(a-b)}e^{\frac{b}{2} \ln\left(\left(1+r^2\cos(2 \theta)\right)^2+r^4\sin(2 \theta)\right)+ib\arctan\left( \frac{r^2\sin(2 \theta)}{1+r^2 \cos(2 \theta)}\right) }\,d \theta\\
&\leq \Bigg|-i r^{a-b}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{i \theta(a-b)}e^{\frac{b}{2} \ln\left(\left(1+r^2\cos(2 \theta)\right)^2+r^4\sin(2 \theta)\right)+ib\arctan\left( \frac{r^2\sin(2 \theta)}{1+r^2 \cos(2 \theta)}\right) }\,d \theta \Bigg|\\ 
& \leq r^{a-b}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{\frac{b}{2} \ln\left(\left(1+r^2\cos(2 \theta)\right)^2+r^4\sin(2 \theta)\right) }\,d \theta
\end{aligned}
$$

taking $\lim_{r \rightarrow 0}$ in the last expression

$$
\begin{aligned}
  \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \,I_{A_2}& \leq \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} r^{a-b}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{\frac{b}{2} \ln\left(\left(1+r^2\cos(2 \theta)\right)^2+r^4\sin(2 \theta)\right) }\,d \theta\\
& = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} r^{a-b}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} e^{\frac{b}{2} \ln\left(\left(1+r^2\cos(2 \theta)\right)^2+r^4\sin(2 \theta)\right) }\,d \theta\\
& = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} r^{a-b}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}  e^{\frac{b}{2} \ln\left(1\right) }\,d \theta\\
& = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} r^{a-b}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \,d \theta\\
& = \pi \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} r^{a-b}\\
& \to 0
\end{aligned}
$$

Is this procedure correct?

Comment: what are the conditions on $a,b$? I see from the last line that you assume $a>b$ and I guess you want $b>-1$ for the other half circles, so it would be helpful to add those

Comment: @Conrad added, thank you!

Comment: if there is no condition relating $a,b$ why $r^{a-b} \to 0$?

Comment: You should have $\operatorname{Re}(a)>\operatorname{Re}(b)$, sorry. I´ll fix it.

Comment: then you can prove your estimates directly as near $0$ you stay within a half plane so $|z^{a-b-1}|=O(|z|^{\Re (a-b)-1})$, the length of the semicircle is $O(|z|)$ and  the other term is bounded so the integral is indeed $O(|z|^{\Re a-\Re b}) \to 0$ , while near $\pm i, z^2+1$ stays within a half plane again so near $i$ with $z=i+r\alpha, |\alpha|=1$ we have $|(z^2+1)^b|=O(r^{\Re b})$, the length of the quarter circle is $O(r)$  and the other term is bounded, so the integral is $O(r^{1+\Re b}) \to 0$ (I mean if you want to write very detailed stuff, I guess what you did is kind of that)

Comment: Thank you. May be I should justify bringing the limit inside the integral and then inside the log.

Comment: you need to be careful and use the estimates as noted since the integrals may a priori be divergent; now in $I_A$ once you take the $r$ term outside, the integral is of a uniformly bounded (in $r$) function so you can take the limit inside by DCT -though you do not really need that since $rO(1) \to 0, r \to 0$ so the uniform boundness of that integral is enough; same with the other two, though I would use that $|\int_Cfdz| \le l(C)\max |f|_C$ as that imho is cleaner

Comment: @Conrad thank you for your comments. Would you like to write an answer so I can consider it as correct?

Comment: did so and explicited a few of the $O$'s in my comments though quite crudely in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline for a fast estimation of the three integrals (the OP computations for $I_A$ are correct and similar but more complicated arguments can be used for the other two integrals, but imho it is simpler for the purpose at hand to use direct estimates).

One uses that $|\int_Cf(z)dz| \le l(C)\max_C|f(z)|$

So for the first integral (semicircle at zero) one has with the parametrization $z=re^{i\theta}$, the estimate $|z^{a-b}| \le Cr^{\Re a-\Re b-1}$ where $C=e^{\pi|\Im a -\Im b|/2}$ and $|(1+z^2)^b|\le C_1$ (with for example $C_1=2^{|\Re b|}e^{\pi |\Im b|}$ though one can do better of course - or simply use that $(1+z^2)^b$ is continuous on a small disc near zero so has a fixed undetermined bound $C_1$), while $l(C)=\pi r$ so the integral is at most $C_2r^{\Re a-\Re b} \to 0, r \to 0$ by the hypothesis

For the integral near $i$ (and same for the integral near $-i)$, one uses $z=i+re^{i\theta}$ with $0 < \theta_0 \le \pi$ and then $|(1+z^2)^b|=|(re^{i\theta})(2i+r{i\theta})|^b \le Cr^b$ with again $C$ easily estimated in terms of $\Re b, \Im b$ (something like $e^{2\pi|\Im b|}3^{|\Re b|}$ works and one can do better if needed), while $|z^{a-b}| \le C_1$ and $l(c) \le \pi r$ so the integral is at most $C_2r^{\Re b +1} \to 0, r \to 0$ by hypothesis